# dir manipulation(__DIR__) not working

Tags: php, directory

the following behaves different in **host**:

```
echo 'DIR:' .__DIR__; // DIR:__DIR__
```

**localhost:**(works fine):

```
DIR:C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www
```

why this different output?

Comment: Can you please clarify the two different locations and the output of each for echoing the __DIR__?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need PHP 5.3 to use `__DIR__`

[Manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

On previous versions you may use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PHP magic constants docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), the `__DIR__` constant was added only in php 5.3.0. You're probably using an older version in your "host" environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<? echo realpath(dirname(__DIR__)); ?>
```

Folder: **localhost or root** :)